# How does ZFS handle redundant copies of a file?

Tags: backup, zfs, checksums, duplicate-files

I have directories with old incremental backups and they are full of redundant copies of various files. My plan was to use ZFS that handles checksums of files and prevent redundancy.

So a model situation:

```
cd /poolname/zalohy
zfs list -p poolname
NAME        USED         AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
poolname  995328  374734901248     98304  /poolname

for i in {0..10}; do echo {1..99999} >file$i.txt; done # I create eleven identical files of the size 588888 bytes.

zfs list -p poolname
NAME         USED         AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
poolname  5677056  374730219520     98304  /poolname

374734901248 - 374730219520 = 4 681 728, i.e. cca 5MB.
```

I expected that 11 identical files (with the same checksum) would take a bit more than 588888 bytes, so ten times less.

Where is the problem. How to handle this redundancy? Is there a better file system than ZFS for this purpose?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### In general

This requires that your ZFS pool (or filesystem) has been configured with **Deduplication** enabled.

From [OpenZFS documentation](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/master/7/zfsconcepts.7.html#Deduplication):

> ##### Deduplication
>
> Deduplication is the process for removing redundant data at the block
> level, reducing the total amount of data stored. If a file system has
> the dedup property enabled, duplicate data blocks are removed
> synchronously. The result is that only unique data is stored and
> common components are shared among files.
>
> Deduplicating data is a very resource-intensive operation. It is
> generally recommended that you have at least 1.25 GiB of RAM per 1 TiB
> of storage when you enable deduplication. Calculating the exact
> requirement depends heavily on the type of data stored in the pool.
>
> Enabling deduplication on an improperly-designed system can result in
> performance issues (slow I/O and administrative operations). It can
> potentially lead to problems importing a pool due to memory
> exhaustion. Deduplication can consume significant processing power
> (CPU) and memory as well as generate additional disk I/O.
>
> Before creating a pool with deduplication enabled, ensure that you
> have planned your hardware requirements appropriately and implemented
> appropriate recovery practices, such as regular backups. Consider
> using the compression property as a less resource-intensive
> alternative.

Deduplication is disabled by default, because as stated above it can be very CPU and memory intensive.

As with all ZFS properties, the `dedup` property can be set on ZFS pool or dataset (filesystem) level, and be inherited by underlying filesystems.

Before enabling `dedup`, you should consider the following:

- Make sure your data will actually benefit from deduplication
- Make sure your system has enough CPU and memory to support the feature

To check if your pool will benefit from `dedup`, you can run *(where `tank` is the pool name)*:

```
sudo zdb -S tank
```

The `-S` simulates `dedup` statistics, and is only usable on the entire pool. The output will be a simulated DDT (deduplication table), and it ends with some stats like:

```
dedup = 1.20, compress = 1.28, copies = 1.03, dedup * compress / copies = 1.50
```

As a rule of thumb, if the estimated `dedup` ratio is above 2, deduplication could be an option to save space. In the above example, since the `dedup` ratio is 1.2, it probably isn't worth it.

To check the `dedup` property of a pool, type:

```
zfs get dedup tank
```

And to set deduplication for the pool, type:

```
sudo zfs set dedup=on tank
```

And to set it only for a dataset (`tank/home`), type:

```
sudo zfs set dedup=on tank/home
```

After `dedup` has been enabled on an existing pool, only newly created data will be deduplicated.

As mentioned in the documentation, it might be a better option to set the `compression=lz4` property on your pool instead *(`lz4` compression have little to no performance impact on most systems)*.

#### For your situation

For your particular situation, I would create a specific dataset (filesystem) only for backup, and enable dedup on only this dataset.

For instance, if you create the ZFS dataset `poolname/backup`:

```
sudo zfs create poolname/backup
```

And then set:

```
sudo zfs set dedup=on poolname/backup
```

In this way, you can test if it works in the expected way. And if you run into problems, you can always transfer your backup to a normal ZFS dataset without `dedup` enabled (but maybe with compression instead).

*NB: It's **not** possible to disable deduplication on a pool or dataset once it's been enabled. In this case, it's only possible to backup the data, destroy the dataset, and move the data to another dataset without deduplication. This is why I would never recommend to enable deduplication on an entire Zpool.*

Comment: Great answer! The only thing I might add is that there are programs that will search for and hard link identical files to save storage. I wrote one to meet my own (similar) needs. https://github.com/HankB/filededup

Comment: @HankB interesting. I've limited my answer to ZFS deduplication, since this was what the OP was initially asking about. However, you could add another answer, explaining alternative methods (like your dedup application), and I would happily upvote if it's a quality answer. 

Comment: Dear Artur Meinild, it is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. I am testing, but I must admit I had much more idealized image of how zfs works. :-)

Comment: Dynamic deduplication at block level is not something easy to accomplish - even for ZFS.

Comment: Yes, I was very naive. I thought that it would write a file on a disk and somehow by the way it would compute a checksum, then compare it with a DB or dataset "FAT table"  and if redundant then hardlink. So one extra SQL query by a single copy. I have no idea what it is doing, but my PC were getting frozen after 100 GB. So ZFS is unusable for this purpose.  Unfortunately. But your answer is definitely a quality answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another helpful user on Mastodon just posted a link to the `hardlink` command (https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/util-linux/hardlink.1.en.html) Which sounds like a better solution to your problem than the program I wrote (mentioned in a comment to the longer and definitive answer WRT ZFS.)

On Ubuntu 22.04, `hardlink` is installed by default (as part of the `util-linux` package), and in your case the default command to run would be (if the directory `/poolname/zalohy` contains the backup data):

```
hardlink /poolname/zalohy
```

Please refer to the `hardlink` [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/hardlink.1.html) for further information about additional options etc.